# Faster start up of Jython possible?

Tags: jython, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

At the moment I'm programming with Jython on my Laptop, but want to use it on my Raspberry Pi3 (Raspbian) later.

Well the start-up time of my program on my Laptop is under 2s, but on my Pi3 it's up to 30s.

I know the issues are that Jython needs time to start up the JVM and even a Pi3 is not as fast as my 3 year old Laptop, but Is it maybe still possible to reduce this start-up time anyway (without over-clocking my Pi)?

EDIT:

At the end I want to use my .py scripts with the jython-standalone.jar v2.7.0

Comment: For the Internet researchers out there:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a solution which is pretty ok for my Project: For small projects OpenJDK seems to be ok, but some things WON'T work with Jython. I had a sleepless weekend until I get this idea to look which version of Java I was using. With the oracle Java(newest Version) it seems to be as fast as on my Laptop Windows etc. (yes it is a little bit slower, but a second less or more is not necessary in my case).
If there is still a faster way to startup, surprise me. :)